# Alterar apenas 1 elemento e não o selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde fiz uma pequena função onde vai alterar todos os itens, exceto o que foi selecionado, mas este item mesmo assim acaba sendo alterado.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin: 20px 0 0 0; padding: 0;">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
        <a class="btn cadastro btn-inscricao" href="Javascript:void(0);" <?= $total_intervalor ? '' : 'disabled';?> onclick="informeCnpj()">
            <div>
                <span>Inscrever o projeto de sua Entidade</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/arrow-right.png">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-right: 0;">
        <a class="btn cadastro btn-feedback" href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="informeCnpj()">
            <div>
                <span>Enviar feedback após o evento</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/arrow-right-white.png">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    function informeCnpj() {
        $('.informe-cnpj').slideDown(400);
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
        $('.cadastro:not(this)').css('opacity', '0.5');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Cara ta muito confusa sua pergunta, o que quer realmente fazer?

Comment: @LeAndrade Tem estes 2 botões, o de Inscrição, e o de Feedback. Por exemplo ao clicar em qualquer um dos dois vai chamar esta função "informeCnpj" que mostra uma div escondida, e diminui a opacidade do botão oposto. Mas ao clicar por exemplo no Inscrição, somente o de feedback deveria ficar com opacidade 0.5, mas ambos (Inscrição e Feedback) ficam com esta opacidade.

Comment: Não seria `$('.cadastro').not(this).css('opacity', '0.5');` ??

Comment: @fernandosavio Ainda assim mexe na opacidade de ambos, ao inves de somente 1.

Comment: Mas esse código deveria estar dentro de um handler de eventos, senão o `this` não vai ser o elemento que você quer

Comment: @fernandosavio como assim?

Comment: Veja [esse exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/gv30bay1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente passar os `this` como parametro ao chamar a função informeCnpj.

Pois o this dentro da função se refere a função e não ao elemen`insira o código aqui`to.

```js
function informeCnpj(elemento) {
  $('.informe-cnpj').slideDown(400);
  $(elemento).css('opacity', '1');
  $('.cadastro').not(elemento).css('opacity', '0.5');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin: 20px 0 0 0; padding: 0;">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
    <a class="btn cadastro btn-inscricao" href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="informeCnpj(this)">
            <div>
                <span>Inscrever o projeto de sua Entidade</span>
            </div>
           
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-right: 0;">
    <a class="btn cadastro btn-feedback" href="Javascript:void(0);" onclick="informeCnpj(this)">
      <div>
        <span>Enviar feedback após o evento</span>
      </div>
   
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Já tentei e não adiantou

Comment: Atualizei a reposta

Comment: Funcionou agora, obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar a opacidade de todos os botões e depois reverter a do clicado... Ficaria dessa forma:

```
<script>
    $(".cadastro").click(function(){
        $('.informe-cnpj').slideDown(400);
        $('.cadastro').css('opacity', '0.5');
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Ainda assim mexe na opacidade de ambos, ao inves de somente 1.